# Weird padding / spacing in list design

Tags: css, navigation, nav

I've been working on a design with three links spanning the width of the device on mobile. I can't figure out why I can't get the spacing right. What looks off?

Here's the design : 
[image]

And here's what the coded version is looking like : 
[image]

Here's my CSS :

```
.b-nav-Wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.b-nav {margin: 0 auto;}

.b-nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.b-nav ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.33%;
}

.b-nav ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(151,151,151);
}

.navNumber {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  font-family: "korolev-condensed",sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.5875em;
  opacity: .50;
}

.navLink {
  float: right;
  width: 65%;
  padding-top: 4px;
  font-family: "mrs-eaves-xl-serif",sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

*edit: here's my HTML :

```
<nav class="b-nav-Wrapper cf">
    <div class="b-nav">
        <ul>
          <li class="active">
            <a href="#">
              <p class="navNumber active">01</p>
              <p class="navLink active">Now Reading</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <p class="navNumber">02</p>
              <p class="navLink">Browse My Books</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <p class="navNumber">03</p>
              <p class="navLink">Notes &amp; Quotes</p>
            </a>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't put your html, that makes us guessing about it. But if `.b-nav ul li` is referred to numbered parts, you should try `width` less than 33.33%. Because just 1px `margin` or `padding` of other elements cause it to break into two lines. If it doesn't solve, put your link or html.

Comment: @ChristopherDavis I've just examined it on jsfiddle.net, you just need to make this change: `.b-nav ul li { width: 32%; display: inline-block; }`